# PHP and Unicode or UTF-8?

Tags: php

My PHP application outputs JSON where special characters are encoded, f.ex. the string "Brøndum" is represented as "Br\u00f8ndum".

Can you tell me which encoding this is, as well as how I get back from "Br\u00f8ndum" to "Brøndum".

I have tried utf8_encode/decode but they don't work as expected.

Thanks!

Comment: `\u00f8` looks like `unicode`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's standard JSON unicode escaping.

You get back to the actual character by using a JSON parser. `json_decode` in the case of PHP.

You can tell PHP not to escape Unicode characters in the first place with the JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE flag.

```
json_encode("Brøndum", JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE)
```

Comment: Oh brilliant. Keeping it simple! It works like a charm. :-) Thanks.

Comment: I just saw that JSON is Unicode-encoded by default, so that explains it as well.

Comment: But that won't have impact on other code. When your code reads the unicode, it will read it as `Brøndum` instead of `Br\u00f8ndum`. Or have you had specific problems with it actually? @skovmand

Answer (score -1):

`mb_detect_encoding` is your [function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php). You just pass it the string and it detects the codification. You can also send it an array with the possibilities (as a regular string like "hello" could potentially be encoded in different codifications.

```
echo mb_detect_encoding("Br\u00f8ndum");
```

Comment: Also important is sending utf-8 content from server, like:
headers('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

Comment: This answers just half of the questio. He want's to now how to detect it, but also how to get it back to the original input.

Comment: That'll return ASCII - there are no not-ascii characters in that string.